# html5 text manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, text, fonts, canvas

I'm trying to write a piece of software to grab strings and pack them
in and ordered layout, like in the image below

[image]

I think that to achieve that result the first step I'd take would be being able 
to calculate the size of a single string in the canvas in order to modify the font-size
to fit the desired width.
so, if any1's got a solution to some built-in function, or a way to perform it
so that I can code it myself that would be nice (very nice).

thanks in advance
k

Comment: you basically want an ocr - google that, but  must tell you that it isn't easy

Comment: In case you decide not to use canvas jquery have 2 nice functions -http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: The OP doesn't want a ocr, he wants to format a string in a particular way

Comment: you mean that I should use the ocr algorithm in order to convert text into an image and then detect its width in a recursive way till I get the matching width?

Comment: @bakudan yeah, I know even mootools has got the same functions, the only problem is the way they threat fonts, and I need to be über-accurate with this issue, cuz this's a font_based project. so in this case canvas gives me stuff like control over kerning baseline and so on.

Comment: LOL @ "even mootools". You think Mootools inferior!? Grr. What you need is to calculate the width of a letter. I don't think that's even possible with canvas... I'm making a jsfiddle for this =)

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to do it without CANVAS, this might come in useful: how to calculate a letter's width: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/sCUac/ in a specific font with a specific size.

**edit**
Or a sentence's width.

Comment: thx m8, I was evaluating this possibility, but I'm a little bit concerned about crossbrowing issues with that, u got some advices?

Comment: There are no xbrowser issues. With this, you get the right width for **that** font on **that** browser in **that** size etc. Just make sure the (very tine) JS suits IE: maybe `Node.offsetWidth` is called differently in IE. You can test that yourself I assume =)

Comment: I couldn't resist. Works perfectly in IE8.

Comment: no way, I just red ur previous comment, and u got me totally wrong: I'm a mootools guy, and to be honest, jquery gives me the creeps :P

Comment: anyhow I'd give it a shot in the js way, the only  problem is that I'll have to use a non standard font.

Comment: Non standard font doesn't matter either. Just load the font with CSS like you would (`font-face` and all that) and pass that font name to the function I made. The browser will render everything like it does (huh?) so you get live results always, and matching the user's browser always. Id' love to see the result!

Comment: And I'm glad you're a Mootools fan! Everybody's talking about jQuery and I no like it either =)

Comment: if u come to the OFF in Barcelona this juse, u're gonna see it ;-)

Comment: Ah Barcelona is a few km too far south. Smuggle it online and secretly pass me the URL?